# Which algorithm for login throttling

Tags: brute-force, password-cracking

I'm about to add a throttle to a login page to stop it being brute forced easily.

I was going to use the [leaky bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket) algorithm to implement the throttle on a per user/IP basis. Is this considered OK or is there a different algorithm that is considered best practice for this situation?

Answer (score 3):

I believe it should be more advanced and it should take into account origin of the requests to prevent DOS. 
Most common is a lockout after a number of attempts but this requires a good unlock procedure that is secure. A lot of sites require a captcha or second factor after a certain amount of attempts.

Always combine lockout or throttling with a strong password policy. How often will an attacker need to guess based on that policy? That is an important factor in designing a lockout/throttling mechanism.

A good approach to protect a login could be:

- Strong password policy
- Captcha after 5 failed attempts for a certain user from a certain IP within 10 minutes.
- Blacklist IP or trigger an alert after 100 failed attempts from a certain IP.

Comment: I will be taking origin into account, lockout is common but client is against it.

Comment: I am looking specifically into which algorithm to use. Leaky bucket seems common, but I have also seen things which double retry time after a certain number of unsuccessful attempts. I am wondering if any is considered more secure or best practice.

Comment: If you can't do a lockout I would do automation prevention after 5 or 10 attempts. Stuff like a captcha to prevent spring to mind. The question is how to have high usability and good security. For good security what counts is the number of guesses/day. For usability it's important at least be able to have 5 attempts and after that still have the ability to log in but it might require some effort. Exponential algorithm doesn't seem suitable since you will either allow a lot of attempts within a short timeframe.

Comment: or you will either have a rapid increase in time to wait which the user cannot circumvent and will lead to long periods of time in which the user has no way of authenticating.

Comment: From a user perspective, exponential is strange. Either I can try to authenticate or I can't. At one moment having to wait 10s and a few attempts later having to wait 10 minutes seems strange.